# AutoSave files in NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, ide, netbeans-8

Tell me please is it possible to NetBeans IDE 8.1 will automatically save files like in IntelliJ IDEA, i.e. not constantly pushing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>.

Comment: what?files in IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: I mean the source files

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to perform autosave in netbeans 8?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31850429/is-there-a-way-to-perform-autosave-in-netbeans-8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved a problem installing the plugin AutoSaveModified.
[link plugin on github](http://github.com/rsmz/AutoSaveModified)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah this question seems to have an answer but to make it easier for the people after.
You basically don't have to install anything at all, just follow this link that is directly from [NetBeans](https://plugins.netbeans.apache.org/catalogue/?id=22). You can just tweak the preferences a bit in the NetBeans IDE and enable the `AutoSave`.