# Auto save plugin for netbeans 8.2

Tags: netbeans, autosave, netbeans-8.2

Is there plugin for auto save feature in netbeans 8.2? I find it from IDE's plugins list but can't find it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to perform autosave in netbeans 8?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31850429/is-there-a-way-to-perform-autosave-in-netbeans-8)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For netbeans 8.1 was a plugin in IDE's plugins list. It was not tested/verified for netbeans 8.2.

I download it(http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/63714/autosavemodified) manually and install it by IDE's plugin`s download section. It works well for me in Ubuntu 16.04!

Answer (score 1):

Since you have not quite clarified your question, I assume you're referring to [this](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/37077/autosave-module-for-6-9-and-later) Netbeans plug-in.

If so, this plugin is not marked as compatible with Netbeans 8.2, that's why you can't find it in the plug-ins list in Netbeans itself.

From my experience, it is possible to manually download and install it in Netbeans 8.1 (even if marked as compatible only with Netbeans 8.0 and lower), <del>but it does not seem to work anymore with Netbeans 8.2 at all</del> and it will work with Netbeans 8.2 also.

**Edit:**

It was not showing as installed at first, and I could not get it to install when I tried, probably because it was already installed when I imported the 8.1 profile in 8.2 (some non-descript error popped up), but after a while I found it to be working. Not sure what exactly happened... a machine reboot, Java update, another thing?

Anyway, I just wanted to confirm that it seems to work with Netbeans 8.2 without any issues.

Comment: If this is the plugin you were asking for, and if my answer helped you, then please mark it as accepted. Thank you.

Comment: Well, a comment along with the downvote would have been helpful to understand how I can improve my answers......